# Matching _{number} with Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying the match part of an image src, an example would be:

> images/preview_1.jpg

and I want to change  _1 to say _6

so I’m trying to match _1

```
function ClickImgOf(filename, itemid){
   var re = new RegExp("(.+)_[0-9])\\.(gif|jpg|jpg|ashx|png)", "g");
   return filename.replace(re, "$1_"+itemid+".$2");
}
```

Is the function I have..

I know that only matches 0-9 but I was just trying to get something to work and even that didn't.

Its fair to say I do not know much about Regex at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unmatched `)` parenthesis there in your pattern. Is that what's throwing you off? Looks okay otherwise. If your problem is being able to match 2-or-more-digit numbers, try `[0-9]+`.

```
function ClickImgOf(filename, itemid){
   var re = new RegExp("(.+)_([0-9]+)\\.(gif|jpg|jpg|ashx|png)", "g");
   return filename.replace(re, "$1_"+itemid+".$3");
}
```

Comment: woops! not the first time missing a ) has led to me pulling my hair out! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`(.+_)[0-9]+(\.(?:gif|jpg|jpg|ashx|png))`

Then you can just do:

```
return filename.replace(re, "$1" + itemid + "$2");
```

Also, download and install this: http://www.ultrapico.com/ExpressoDownload.htm

It's invaluable when working with regular expressions.

Comment: Have you seen this -> http://regexhero.net/tester/ ? its also pretty damn good when working with regex.

Comment: Yeah, that's also good! Basically you just need a regex tester of some description, it'll save a lot of time as I'm sure you've found! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build your regex using the regex object, it's both easier and performs better to use a literal.

```
function ClickImgOf(filename, itemid) {
   return filename.replace(/_\d+\.(gif|jpg|jpg|ashx|png)$/g, '_'+itemid+'.$2');
}
```